# How to vertically center content within a ListView footer?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have posted the exact layout below.  I want to show an image and text vertically centered inside the footer.  I have applied:

```
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
```

To both the LinearLayout containing these elements and the TextView inside but nevertheless the whole line  image and text appears way too far towards the top of the footer.  I want it centered vertically but instead it is in the top 30 % of the footer at all times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someMessageMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone"        
     android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="16dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/picimg" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:text="This message appears way to close to the top of the footer. It should be along with the image in the center:"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    style="@style/mybuttonstyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/lbl_send"
    android:visibility="gone" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your layout it seems you haven't given android:paddingTop to your TextView. Thats why its appearing to the top. 
Moreover you can also remove android:paddingTop from ImageView if that suits to your layout.
Hope that helps.

Comment: true but the TextView and image are both at same level and within a second LinearLayout. It is to this whole inner layout that I have given the center_vertical instruction

Comment: I don't see how the centering will work inside your vertical linear layout. You will basically have three "boxes" on top of each other, and there's no room for things to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the image? I think the problem is in your second `LinearLayout`. You're setting the height to be "wrap_content" so that means that it will only be as big as the biggest child. If the image and the text are about the same height, then it won't seem as if anything is getting centered. You can test this theory by forcing the height to be something big enough.

Comment: its a small image and its just to the left of the text. So both together are to be vertically centered.  Note also that both are within a second LinearLayout so the whole thing should have been centered vertically per the instruction to the inner LinearLayout.